# Api bridging possibilities in Realm platform Developer Edition

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

API Bridging is fully supported in Professional Edition. Is there a way to connect third party database using realm with Developer Edition ?

Comment: I think data connectors are in enterprise edition

Comment: Yes it really is in enterprise edition. But i am looking for the ways how to connect third party API using developer Edtition, what are the possibilities.